# KDE Dolphin Service Menu to Print PDFs

Tags: printing, contextmenu, right-click, kde-plasma, file-manager

I tried to create a service menu so that I can print pdf files directly from dolphin's context menu.

Here's the print-pdf.desktop file:

```
[Desktop Action print-pdf]
Exec=/home/me/.kde/share/kde4/services/print-pdf.sh %D %U
Icon=stock_print
Name=Print PDF

[Desktop Entry]
Actions=print-pdf
Icon=print
MimeType=application/pdf
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
Type=Service
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel
```

And here's the script it's supposed to execute:

```
#! /bin/bash
for FILE in *.pdf;
do lp $FILE;
done
```

However, as to be expected, all pdf files are printing at once instead of only those selected. I tried using '$1' as well, but that did nothing.

Is there a way to tell dolphin to process **only** selected files?

Answer (score 3):

Following the [.desktop spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s07.html), we can use `%f` to pass in a single file as an argument (`%D` is deprecated).
Using `%f` has the additional benefit that we do not need to loop over the selected files ourselves.

So to make your service menu work, replace the `Exec=...` line with

```
Exec=lp %f
```

Furthermore the .desktop file has to be placed in

```
~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/
```

to be recognised by Dolphin. I wish this was documented somewhere.